# Get value of textarea with this element and not identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to check empty textarea in tinymce

```
$(".tooltip-empty-editor").each(function() {        

    if( $.trim( tinymce.get(this).getContent() ) == '' ) { 
        // .....
    }

});
```

html

```
<textarea class="editor tooltip-empty-editor " name="modif" >....</textarea>
```

But this i got error `tinymce.get(this).getContent()` with `this` he expect a ID.

How can I use this `with` tinymce to get value of textarea ?

Comment: Can you show the relation of the tooltip to the textarea in HTML?

Comment: @TimVermaelen it's a class in the textarea element. I update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you define the `id` and access it as follows?

```
$(".tooltip-empty-editor").each(function() {        

    if( $.trim( tinymce.get($(this).attr("id")).getContent() ) == '' ) { 
        // .....
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your textarea's are related to eachother, you could try to find the index. You need a `sibling`, or if they're all children of the same node (`parent`) no need to bother => `$(this).index()`

If you only have one on the page => textarea = tinymce.get(0)

**HTML expectation:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="sibling">
        <textarea class="editor tooltip-empty-editor " name="modif" >....</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="sibling">
        <textarea class="editor tooltip-empty-editor " name="modif" >....</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".tooltip-empty-editor").each(function() {
    var index = $(this).closest('.sibling').index(),
        //index = $(this).index(),
        textarea = tinymce.get(index); // get() requires an id or a number

    if( $.trim( textarea.getContent() ) == '' ) {
        // .....
    }
});
```

If your html is polluted with other elements on the parent, you'll need to use `.filter()` to get the index from.

Comment: thanks for help man.but my textarea can't be related like you have done.

Answer (score 1):

Per the product documentation, the `get()` API for TinyMCE *"Returns an editor instance by id"*.  The id parameter is expected to be a **String**.  In your example you seems to be trying to pass it the "this" object which is not a String.

I would give each textarea on the page a unique ID attribute and you can then reference each textarea using that ID.

As one other poster noted you can also use an integer to access each TinyMCE instance on the page (e.g. `tinymce.get(0)` and `tinymce.get(1)`)